# Similarity of $3\times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

I am considering $3\times 3 $ matrices, one of them is diagonalizable i.e

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
3&0&4\\
0&-1&0\\
-2&0&-3
\end{array}\right]= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&0&-2\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&1
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&0&-2\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&1
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=P_1DP_1^{-1}.
$$
The second one is not diagonalizable, and we have
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
0&-1&1\\
0&0&-1
\end{array}\right]= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1&1&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{array}\right]^{-1}=P_2JP_2^{-1}.
$$
Matrices $A$ and $B$ are called similar if there exists an invertible  matrix P such that
$ B=P^{-1}AP$.

In my example $A$ and $B$ are not similar, because one of them is diagonalizable and the second is not diagonalizable. I am not sure, that my explaination is proper. I would be grateful for your advices, how to explain that this matrices are not similar.

Comment: You say that $B$ is not diagonalizable, but then write it as $B=PJP^{-1}$ and then $B\sim J$?

Comment: $J$ is Jordan matrix

Comment: But the original matrix $B$ is already a Jordan matrix. What else do you want?

Comment: oh.... I did not noticed it...  (too much work.) But i am not sure, that my explaination about similarity is proper.

Comment: Well, $J$ is Jordan matrix, I didn't read correctly the matrix. Now, in order you see if $A$ and $B$ are similar you can see if we can find  a matrix $P$ such that $AP=PB$. You can use brute force defining $P=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: A matrix $A$ and a matrix $D$ are said to be similar if $P$ is an invertible matrix such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. It is not clear to me how you intend to bring $A$ and $B$ into such a relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable matrix and $B$ is a Jordan matrix which is not a diagonal matrix, $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Or you can say that$$\dim\{v\in\Bbb R^3\mid A.v=-v\}=2,$$whereas$$\dim\{v\in\Bbb R^3\mid B.v=-v\}=1,$$which also proves that $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Comment: thank you very much for explaination

Answer (score 2):

By contradiction, suppose that $A\sim B$, then there exists a matrix $P$ regular such that $AP=PB$. Let $P=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$ be a matrix such that $\boxed{\det(P)\not=0}$.

A bit of algebra shows that

- $AP=\begin{pmatrix}3&0&4\\0&-1&0\\-2&0&-3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3a+4g&3b+4h&3c+4i\\-d&-e&-f\\-2a-3g&-2b-3h&-2c-3i \end{pmatrix}$.
- $PB=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&1\\0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\g-d&h-e&i-f\\-g&-h&-i \end{pmatrix}$

But since we supposed that $AP=PB$ that is true if and only if
$$a=0,\quad b=0,\quad c=0,\quad g=0,\quad h=0,\quad i=0$$
for $d,e,f\in {\bf R}$, but thus
$$\det(P)=\det\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\d&e&f\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix} \implies \boxed{\det(P)=0}$$
and it is a contradiction.

Therefore, $A$ is not similar to the matrix  $B$.

Comment: We consider $AP=PB$, i think.

Comment: Of course, I fixed this just right now.